# Eliminate spaces in filename and rename (cywgin)

Tags: bash, cygwin, mv

I use cygwin on top of windows.
I have a windows file that contains files with spaces. I want to get rid of the spaces between the characters and rename the files.

```
IMG_4089 - Copy - Copy.JPG
IMG_4089 - Copy.JPG
IMG_4092 - Copy - Copy.JPG
IMG_4092 - Copy (2).JPG
IMG_4092 - Copy.JPG
IMG_4093 - Copy - Copy.JPG
IMG_4093 - Copy (2).JPG
IMG_4093 - Copy.JPG
```

usually the mv command in bash works in linux

```
$ cat get_rid_of_spaces.sh
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n' ;

for i in *
do
        jay=$i ;
        jay2=$(echo $i | sed -e "s/ //g")
        echo $jay2 "--->" $jay
        mv $jay2 $jay
        sleep .5 ;
done
```

However I keep getting these errors.

```
IMG_4089-Copy-Copy.JPG ---> IMG_4089 - Copy - Copy.JPG
mv: cannot stat 'IMG_4089-Copy-Copy.JPG': No such file or directory

IMG_4089-Copy.JPG ---> IMG_4089 - Copy.JPG
mv: cannot stat 'IMG_4089-Copy.JPG': No such file or directory


IMG_4092-Copy-Copy.JPG ---> IMG_4092 - Copy - Copy.JPG
mv: cannot stat 'IMG_4092-Copy-Copy.JPG': No such file or directory

IMG_4092-Copy(2).JPG ---> IMG_4092 - Copy (2).JPG
mv: cannot stat 'IMG_4092-Copy(2).JPG': No such file or directory

IMG_4092-Copy.JPG ---> IMG_4092 - Copy.JPG
mv: cannot stat 'IMG_4092-Copy.JPG': No such file or directory

IMG_4093-Copy-Copy.JPG ---> IMG_4093 - Copy - Copy.JPG
mv: cannot stat 'IMG_4093-Copy-Copy.JPG': No such file or directory

IMG_4093-Copy(2).JPG ---> IMG_4093 - Copy (2).JPG
mv: cannot stat 'IMG_4093-Copy(2).JPG': No such file or directory

IMG_4093-Copy.JPG ---> IMG_4093 - Copy.JPG
mv: cannot stat 'IMG_4093-Copy.JPG': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Quote your variables

Comment: You're trying to use the new filename as the first argument to `mv`, but it has to be the second one...? Also, you have to quote the filenames with spaces.

Comment: Consider making a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here.

Comment: shell check dot net - never heard of it - will do - the question was worth that !

Comment: BTW, consider `for i in *[[:space:]]*; do` to not even look at filenames that don't contain spaces at all. (If you use `shopt -s nullglob` before that point, that will prevent the glob from expanding to itself if there are no matches).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

Swap `$jay` and `$jay2`. The `mv` command uses the first argument as the source and the second argument as the destination:

```
mv sourceFile destinationFile
```

Don't forget to quote, since you have spaces:

```
mv "$jay" "$jay2"
```

## Alternative

If you have `rename` installed, you can replace your script with the following command:

```
rename 's/ //g' *
```

The `s/ //g` means substitute (`s`) space (`/ /`) with the empty string (`//`) globally (`g`).
The wildcard `*` specfies the files to be renamed, that is all files in the working directory.

Comment: Leaving the OP using `sed` rather than a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) in the non-`rename` case is unfortunate. Much more efficient to `mv "$jay" "${jay//[[:space:]]/}"` than to run a separate copy of `sed` for each file.

Comment: @Socowi - thanks man - layup !